# How to change hovertext window size in Dash/Plotly?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

How to change the size of the hovertext window ? I’m using `hovermode=‘x unified’` and I’d like to see full name of trace.

[image]

Comment: I am not sure if you can change the size of the hovertext window itself (unless you make the font larger, but that won't help with text visibility). however you could try inserting `<br>` into the string names being used in the hovertext and see if that works

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own template like that:

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.gapminder().query("continent=='Oceania'")

fig = px.line(df, x="year", y="lifeExp", color="country")
fig.update_traces(mode="markers+lines", 
                  hovertemplate=  "Year: it is easy to print the title %{x}<br>" +
                                   "y: %{y}<br>")

fig.update_layout(hovermode="x unified")

fig.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
    hoverlabel = dict(namelength = -1)
```

or a number of characters, on each trace.

See the [original post](https://community.plotly.com/t/re-size-hover-info-box/955/11)

The documentation for the Hoverlabel namelength property : [here](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.graph_objects.treemap.html#plotly.graph_objects.treemap.Hoverlabel)